# Insert AppleScript variables without comma seperating them from text

Tags: macos, shell-script, applescript

I need to run a shell script in an applescript like this

```
set key_status to (do shell script "defaults read " & path_to_plist & " PlistKey")
```

But unix gives an error because this script seems to seperate path_to_plist and  PlistKey
with a comma so it tries to run this

```
defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/plist_name, PlistKey
```

And that gives this error

> The domain/default pair does not exist

Anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried
    `set key_status to (do shell script " defaults read  & path_to_plist & \" PlistKey\" ")`

?